# NavigationBar color de fondo

Tags: java, android, android-navigationview

Tengo el siguiente `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/HintHomeMonto"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:background="@color/white"
        />
```

Cuando se abra como no es a pantalla completa , la actividad de fondo queda como sombreado , me gustaría que no estuviera este sombreado no se como se llama ni como buscarlo , si alguien me ilumina muchas gracias.

Me refiero a que cuando abre queda como opaco el fondo que no es ocupado por el `navigationview` este me gustaría que no este ese opaco gracias

Comment: Puedes cambiarlo a transparente programaticamente usando `setScrimColor` de esta forma: `drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Comment: @A.Palacio por favor comentalo como respuesta para aceptartela , pase un buen rato buscando esto –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para quitar el degradado al abrir el `NavigationDrawer`, puedes utilizar la propiedad `setScrimColor` que te permite cambiar el color .

**Código:**

```
drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```